# how to send the content in a list from server in twisted python?

Tags: python, list, chat, twisted, transport

I have a list related to multiclient chat server problem. This is the list ['talk', client_n, message]. How can I send 'message' to 'client_n' from the server in twisted python using transport.write()?

I wrote the code in two ways. But both are not working.

1st way:

```
  data = data.strip()
  dat1 = data.split()
  dat2 = ' '.join(dat1)
  l = dat2[5:12]
  m = dat2[13:]
  l.transport.write(m)
```

2nd way:

```
 data = data.strip()
 dat1 = data.split()
 l1 = dat1[1]
 m1 = dat1[2]
 if l1 in self.factory.clients:
    l1.transport.write(m1)
```

But in both I got attribute error.

```
exceptions.AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'transport'
```

Can anybody give me a solution for this, please?

Answer (score 6):

What is self.factory.clients?  Is it perhaps a dictionary?  Do you really want to do something like:

```
client = self.factory.clients.get(client_n)
if client:
    client.transport.write(message)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert, but maybe you should consider to serialize and deserialize your list through [JSON](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html) ?